# REST - Common practice for "change-all" mutations

Tags: rest, http

In my app there is a button which (when clicked) should apply some mutation to all entities (of a certain type). Assuming my entities are "purchases" clicking on the "confirm all" button should result in the server/db setting the "confirmed" field of all "purchases" to "true".

I have the code that does this on the server side. My question is this: what is the URI that I should use for this action?

POST seems like a wrong choice as this action *is* idempotent. Thus, I am left with PUT. two ideas come to mind:

- `PUT /purchases?confirmed=true`
- `PUT /purchaes/__all__?confirmed=true`

Is there any well established convention?

EDIT

There is a third option (suggested by Markus):

- `PUT /confirmations/?confirmed=true`

Of course, this can work and clearly has its merits. The (only) problem that I find with it is the confirmations is not an en entity in my system. In particular there is no `GET /confirmations/some_id` URI which may be confusing.

Comment: PUT is definitely the way to go. As for the resource, you seem to have missed a noun: confirmations. So I'd have `PUT /confirmations/?confirmed=true`

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg. That's interesting. Didn't think of that. Added your suggestion (+ my slight concern about it) to the post. What do you think?

Comment: They may not be an entity _class_ on your system, but obviously they are a logical entity. Maybe even and interesting one to provide an API for ("Has my order 12345 be confirmed? Let's ask `/confirmations/12345`! Ah, my order has been confirmed at this date and this time by that company/operator/whateverSubject."). This is especially true since a confirmed order is unlikely to be allowed to be changed, effectively making it another class of purchase - a confirmed one.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, the URI you should use for this operation is whatever URI the collection of purchases returned for that action. The URI semantics shouldn't matter.

Second, when we say POST isn't idempotent, what we are saying is that the client can't assume by default that the operation is idempotent. The semantics of the POST method are entirely within your control, and that's why they must be documented and you can't rely on the client knowing beforehand what it does, as is the case with GET, PUT and DELETE.

In simple terms, having a PUT operation that isn't idempotent is a violation of the HTTP method semantics, but having a POST that is idempotent is fine.

Third, what you're doing is RPC, not REST. For instance:

```
PUT /purchases?confirmed=true
```

You're simply calling a method by passing parameters. The only way this could make sense in REST would be if you were creating or replacing a set of purchases to replace the subset where `confirmed=true`, which would be the exact opposite of what you want. If you want to do something like that, you should use POST, not PUT.

It's clear that your confirmation is a partial update, so you shouldn't be using PUT at all. As a general rule, if you're trying to define a separate semantics coupled to a particular resource for GET, PUT, PATCH and DELETE, you're doing wrong. Those methods should be generic and work in the exact same way for everything. If you need to couple some URI and method to a particular resource state transition, do it with POST.

I don't know the details of the API, but it looks like you're using query string parameters as payload parameters interchangeably. That's not a good idea either, since you can't treat URIs as atomic identifiers.

If your URIs were atomic, you could say this returns all unconfirmed purchases:

```
GET /purchases?confirmed=false
```

And you could document POST as the method to perform partial updates in bulk, changing the filtered subset:

```
POST /purchases?confirmed=false

{ "confirmed": true }
```

If you insist on using PUT, you should do something like this. If you have the URI below which returns a global confirmed status by reducing all purchases with AND:

```
GET /purchases/confirmation

{ "confirmed": False }
```

Then you could make something like:

```
PUT /purchases/confirmation

{ "confirmed": true }
```